# uber pool no_drivers_available

Tags: api, pool, uber-api

has anyone had this issue? ive been using uber api for months to order rides, but last week something changed, and evey time i try ordering uber pool, the v1.2/requests/estimate endpoint gives me an estimate and fare_id, and when i book the ride, i get http 200 success. but then a few minutes later i get error no_drivers_available. this does not seem to happen using uberX. i've tried ordering rides in places that defintely have drivers (i.e manhattan) but i always get the same error after a few minutes

Comment: hrmm-- i have not seen that problem. I recently booked a pool ride successfully through the API.

Comment: can you tell me the flow of your app, i.e., which endpoints your hitting, in which order, and any delays between

Comment: I am just hitting the requests/estimate endpoint for the product I want, and then the request endpoint with the returned fare ID. Instructions below, maybe you can use deeplinks and deeplink into the uber app instead if you are having trouble? Maybe try an area other than NY?

"Use the request estimate endpoint POST /requests/estimate with a product_id to get a fare_id. The fare_id is used to set an upfront fare and arrival time for a trip.
Request a ride using the request endpoint POST /requests with the fare_id returned in the previous step."

Comment: yes ive tried everything, its been running smoothly for months, ive ordered hundreds of rides, but now it wont work. the bug started by returning invalid_fare_id every time i booked a ride with the request endpoint, even within a few seconds of getting an estimate. so i changed my code to get estimate via price and time endpoint, and then get request estimate, and immediately call request to order the ride. that worked for uberX, but like i said, i cant get pool to work. do you mind telling me parameters your using so i can try exact same parameters?

Comment: have you ever solved it?